# Issue converting JSON to HashMap in Android

Tags: android, json, hashmap, type-conversion

I have `JSONArray` and when I decode `JSON` to `HashMap` at that time `HashMap` take last value of `JSONArray`.

here my code:

```
QjArray = new JSONArray(Questionresult);
JSONObject json_data  = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0; i<QjArray.length(); i++) {
    objJMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    json_data = QjArray.getJSONObject(i);

    jQuestionName =json_data.getString("QuestionName");
    objJMap.put("QuestionName",jQuestionName);

    jQuestiontypeid = json_data.getInt("Questiontypeid");
    String Qid = jQuestiontypeid.toString();
    objJMap.put("Questiontypeid", Qid);

    jAnswertypeid = json_data.getInt("Answertypeid");
    String Aid = jAnswertypeid.toString();
    objJMap.put("Answertypeid", Aid);
}
```

My `JSONArray`:

```
This is question list[{"QuestionID":"1","QuestionName":"when you come","Questiontypeid":"1","Answertypeid":"1"},{"QuestionID":"2","QuestionName":"about your words","Questiontypeid":"1","Answertypeid":"2"},{"QuestionID":"3","QuestionName":"you want extra service?","Questiontypeid":"1","Answertypeid":"3"},{"QuestionID":"4","QuestionName":"performance of quality ?","Questiontypeid":"1","Answertypeid":"4"},{"QuestionID":"5","QuestionName":"performance of staff?","Questiontypeid":"1","Answertypeid":"5"},{"QuestionID":"6","QuestionName":"when you left room ?","Questiontypeid":"2","Answertypeid":"1"},{"QuestionID":"7","QuestionName":"your words about roomservice ?","Questiontypeid":"2","Answertypeid":"2"},{"QuestionID":"8","QuestionName":"you like roomservice ?","Questiontypeid":"2","Answertypeid":"3"},{"QuestionID":"9","QuestionName":"performance room service ?","Questiontypeid":"2","Answertypeid":"4"},{"QuestionID":"10","QuestionName":"performance room service staff?","Questiontypeid":"2","Answertypeid":"5"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are certain problems in your logic. For every JSON object u are creating new HashMap object inside for loop, so u will loose any previous data. Also HashMap will override new Data, so you will have only final data. What u can do is that create an arrayList of Hashmap....

```
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<STring, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i<QjArray.length(); i++) {

           objJMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
........
           data.add(objJMap);
    ...}
```

Comment: now json code in arraylist  and now how to iterator that arraylist?

Comment: i finsh this now how to Iterate Arraylist ?how to use it??

Comment: u can find it easily, just search a bit

Answer (score 2):

This is because your code re initializes the HashMap after every loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i<QjArray.length(); i++) {
             objJMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
....
}
```

Place the HashMap outside the loop and it will work fine.

```
objJMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
for (int i = 0; i<QjArray.length(); i++) {
....
}
```